# React library bundled with rollup producers errors in tests after upgrading to v3

Tags: reactjs, antd, rollup

I have a React library bundled with Rollup. When using this library in other projects, I started getting errors in my tests after upgrading to rollup v3. Previously everything worked fine (if I use 2.x, it works).

This is the kind of error I'm getting:

```js
TypeError: generatePicker is not a function
```

This is my config:

```js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import filesize from 'rollup-plugin-filesize';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import progress from 'rollup-plugin-progress';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';

import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

export default {
  external: ['rc-picker/lib/generate/dateFns', '@ant-design/icons'],
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    json(),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
    }),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
      tsconfigOverride: {
        exclude: [
          '**/__tests__',
          '**/*.(spec|test).ts',
          '.storybook/',
          '**/*.stories.tsx',
        ],
      },
    }),
    commonjs(),
    postcss({
      namedExports: true,
    }),
    progress(),
    filesize(),
    visualizer(),
  ],
};
```

Any idea of what could be going on? The error references an Ant Design function, which is a peer dependency, so not sure why the bundling is making this fail. Also, this fails independently of the tested component using said function, but only by importing anything within the library it makes it fail.